# macOS in recovery mode does not accept my credentials

Tags: macos, install, recovery

Today when I tried to unlock my Mac (Sonoma 14.3) I noticed it's not sleep, it was shutdown. When I logged nothing was working, it said the Main app cannot load accounts, the keychain is not working, etc. I restarted it then I could not login again. After entering my password for the first time it shows another screen with username and password fields but it does not accept my username and password combination. I've been even trying to reinstall the OS but it does not work either.

The logs there says:

```
Operation queue failed with error: Error Domain=com.apple.OSInstallerSetup.error Code=1004 "An error occurred loading the update." UserInfo=(NSLocaLizedDescription-An error occurred loading the update.)
Stopped operation queue with Error Domain=com.apple.OSInstallerSetup.error Code=1004 "An error occurred loading the update." UserInfo=(NSLocaLizedDescription=An error occurred loading the update.)
```

I've tried a standalone installer, builtin recovery and internet recovery, all lead to the same error.

Intel iMac 2019, 2TB SSD, 64GB RAM.

[image]